# Is latino sine flexione dead?

Tags: history, natural-languages

Latino sine flexione is a variant of Latin created by Peano in 1903. As far as I know it was used in scientific literature but since forgotten.

I found [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/latinosineflexio/) and a few discussions on [Duolingo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/26079920/What-about-Latino-Sine-Flexione-aka-Peano%E2%80%99s-Interlingua) but not a single speaker.
A quite complete grammar can be found [here](http://mi.anihost.ru/Peano/lsf.htm).

Is this wonderful project dead?

*Note*: I posted the same question [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-latino-sine-flexione-dead) and was suggested to "address a different community".

Comment: First I was - hm, what - I've never heard about it, than I've opened Wiki and realized that it's Interlingua ) but it shouldn't be confuse with the other, more famous Interlingua )

Comment: It is Interlingua de Peano that is different from Interlingua that you may think of.

Comment: no, I'm aware that there are two, I meant this one exactly. Never liked it though )

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: it's basically a Latin without cases and conjugations. As a native Russian speaker who learnt Latin in school LSF sounded compared to Latin  like a Bulgarian to Russian - similar but "frozen".

Comment: Inflexions are replaced by prepositions, would you say English, Spanish, French, Italian, Portuguez… are frozen?

Comment: the thing is that LSF felt too much like Latin to me, I've never have the same problem with any Romance language since they went quite far away from Latin. But I did have the same feeling with Bulgarian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100553/discussion-between-blincer-and-shabunc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is obviously not completely dead, there is at least one blogger posting short news items in Latino Sine Flexione here http://nuntios.blogspot.com/search/label/Latino%20sine%20Flexione

I don't know whether there is a functional speech community for this language left.

EDIT: There is another life sign of Latino sine flexione: Someone [created a LaTeX package for it](https://ctan.org/pkg/latino-sine-flexione)!

Comment: Thank you for sharing the blog!

Comment: As an adjunct to this answer, I came across what I think must be LSF in a Duolingo forum. Sòmebody out there is using LSF!

Comment: I am working on its revival: https://acproil.github.io :)